# Why is is_resource failing using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli and trying to check to see if it is a resource before using the results. It is failing and I do not know why. I know the sql being sent in is correct and the connection is working fine.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function exec_query($sql) {
        // Check if sql is not empty 
        if (!empty($sql)) {
            $sql = sprintf('%s', $sql);
            // Get connected 
            $this->db_conn = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,  $this->db_user,  $this->db_pass, $this->db_name)); 
            // Execute Query 
            $this->db_qry = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql);                     
            if (!$this->db_qry) 
                {
                    
                    return false; 
                }
            else { 
                
                if (is_resource($this->db_qry) && get_resource_type($this->db_qry) === 'mysqli') {
                    
                    return $this->db_qry;
                } else {
                    
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->close_conn();

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"It is failing..."_? You probably mean your `exec_query()` returns `false`? There are three situations in your code where this can happen. Which one is it?

Comment: Please debug your code to check exactly what is not returning what you expect. Does `is_resource($this->db_qry)` return `false`? Is `get_resource_type($this->db_qry)` not equal to `'mysqli'`? The title of your question makes it sound like it is the first, but your code doesn't actually check for this.

Comment: Yes, is_resource($this->db_qry) is returning false. I would expect it "not" to return false in the example above.

Comment: mysqli doesn't have any functions that return a resource type. What are you checking here?

Comment: Dharman, you may have just answered my question. I am converting from an ODBC connection with used is_resource. It seems like this would be unnecessary for mysqli.

Comment: Unrelated, but this function does too many things. It connects to DB, executes query and checks whether `$sql` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using code generated by some auto migration software. It looks like this code was meant to migrate from `mysql_*` API to mysqli but it didn't consider `is_resource`. You need to fix this manually.

The mysqli extension does not use resource type. This check makes no sense here. Furthermore, you should consider switching on mysqli error reporting. With automatic error reporting you don't need any checking like you are doing now. If an error happens then mysqli will throw an exception. To do that, just add this line before you connect to the database:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And then you can remove all these weird `if` statements after mysqli function calls.